# Trigger SQLPLUS

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a table with the columns(id,t1, t2, t3, mark) with types (number, integer, integer, integer, float) respectively
I wanna insert the values of the student id, test 1 score, test2 score and test 3 score.
Using a trigger i wanna insert the average of the three test scores in the column 'mark'.

Here's the trigger i wrote but its giving compilation errors.

```
create or replace trigger trigger_2 before insert on grades
     for each row

declare
total integer ;
begin
total := :NEW.t1 + :NEW.t2 + :NEW.t3    
:NEW.mark := total/3.0;
end;
SQL> /

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.`
```

Comment: What database is this?

Comment: Also, you seem to have missed semi column at the end of this line `total := :NEW.t1 + :NEW.t2 + :NEW.t3  `

Comment: What does `show error` tell you?

Comment: @Incognito this is most probably the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is (in case you're on Oracle 10g):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_2
  BEFORE INSERT ON grades
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :NEW.mark := (:NEW.t1 + :NEW.t2 + :NEW.t3)/3;
END;
/
```

Comment: Committing inside a trigger is a _very_ bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

ya just try this template dude

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER <trigger_name>
      BEFORE INSERT ON grades
      FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      :NEW.mark := (:NEW.<val1> + :NEW.<val2> + :NEW.<val3>...<valn>)/n;
    END;
    /
```